# Avoid long if/else statement by returning any combination of three values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a Vue filter function as a string helper and ran into an interesting problem. I feel as if there's got to be a much simpler solution but can't for the life of me come up with one or find a similar issue here in SO.

The function passes in a user object which can contain a `city`, `state`, and `country` value. Here's what it currently looks like:

```
Vue.filter('userLocation', function(user) {
  const { city, state } = user;
  if (city && state) {
    return `${city}, ${state}`;
  } else if (!city && state) {
    return `${state}`;
  } else if (city && !state) {
    return `${city}`;
  } else {
    return 'Please update your location settings!';
  }
});
```

Currently this function is only returning city and state values, and is already pretty ugly, however now I'm wanting to add in country as well which only make it that much more complicated.

Essentially I want the function to return any combination of the three values. So if country isn't included, return city and state. If state isn't included, return city and country, etc. Is there a better (possibly ES6) solution to account for all the scenarios, instead of writing so many if/else conditionals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few tricks you can do, but once you get to three items like that, I'd probably use an array:

```
Vue.filter('userLocation', function(user) {
  const { city, state, country } = user;
  return [city, state, country].filter(Boolean).join(", ") || 'Please update your location settings!';
});
```

or

```
Vue.filter('userLocation', function(user) {
  return [user.city, user.state, user.country].filter(Boolean).join(", ") || 'Please update your location settings!';
});
```

Live Example of the string-from-user bit:

```js
function example(user) {
    return [user.city, user.state, user.country].filter(Boolean).join(", ") || 'Please update your location settings!';
}

function test(user) {
    console.log(example(user));
}

test({
  city: "Dallas",
  state: "Texas",
  country: "USA"
});
test({
  city: "San Francisco"
});
test({
  city: "Denver",
  state: "Colorado"
});
test({
  state: "Michigan"
});
test({
  city: "Middlesborough",
  country: "UK"
});
test({
});
```

How those work:

- `[city, state]` creates an array.
- `.filter(Boolean)` filters out any *falsy* values from it (such as blank strings). The resulting array will have zero, one, or two entries.
- `.join(", ")` joins the entries with a comma and space as the separator. If there are fewer than two entries, there won't be any separator.
- `|| '...'` uses the right-hand operand if the left-hand operand is falsy (such as an empty string). (More on my anemic little blog: [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).)

---

You might want to put `.trim()` on `city` and `state` in case they contain just whitespace.

Comment: The first solution seems very neat and concise.

Comment: Went with the first option and it works perfectly! Your examples don't include country as a property on the user object, but simply adding it into the return array still of course works as expected. Thank you! Looks like I've got some learning to do with regards to `.filter`

Comment: @J.Jackson - Doh! Missed the country thing. :-)